# SSL TcpClient C# .Net Compact Framework 1.0

Tags: c#, ssl, compact-framework

I am looking for connecting TcpClient over SSL. I am using .Net compact framework 1.0. Is there is opensource (or commercial) library that provides functionality similar to System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient but over ssl.

Thanks,
Kishore.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the SocketPro-library by Udaparts which supports SSL. You may use this for free (even commercially) as far as I have understood. Please see:
[SocketPro](http://www.udaparts.com/document/articles/demome.htm)

This library works great with most connections which requires SSL. However, there is a problem with GMail for unknown reasons although this can be easily resolved by using above library together with those of OpenSSL. If you search the support-forum at UdaParts you can find links for donwloading the extra OpenSSL-libraries.

Good luck!